# Storing multiple datatypes in a single HashMap

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I want to put an array of `int` and a `String` into a `HashMap`. Is this possible? what is the proper way to that?

This is my HashMap:

```
Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();

    stringMap.put("Text","fish" );
    stringMap.put("Diet","false");
    stringMap.put("CookingTime", "60");
    stringMap.put("OptionId", [7,8,8]);
```

I know this line is wrong - how do I store an array in a `HashMap`?

```
    stringMap.put("OptionId", [7,8,8]);
```

Comment: Because that's not the syntax to declare an array.

Comment: Hello You Put This array as String like "7,8,8" and then convert this string to array using

String OptionId = "7,8,81"
String []yourArray=date.split("[,]");

Comment: I know it , as I asked I want to know how to put array of int along with strings  in HashMap

Comment: Array is not a string. Use Map<String, Object> instead of Map<String, String>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instantiate an array in java by doing

```
someMap.put("OptionId", new int[]{7,8,8});
```

Otherwise you will need a function that returns those values in an array.

For your case: if you want to create a HashMap of multiple datatypes you can use

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

You can then put anything you want in

```
map.put("key1", "A String");
map.put("key2",  new int[]{7,8,8});
map.put("key3", 123);
```

Except now the tricky part is you don't know what is what so you need to use `instanceof` to parse the map unless you know what type of object is at a key then you can just `cast` it to that type.

```
if(map.get("key1") instanceof String)
    String s = (String) map.get("key1"); // s = "A String"
```

or

```
int[] arr = (int[]) map.get("key2"); // arr = {7,8,8}
```